# Curl Post in Java

Tags: java, curl, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a java equivalent of this:

```
curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=sk_test_px1LcMW6VWVSWKrRT4MuHvTY \
  -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

in java as per the doc found here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth#token-request. This is what I have arrived at, but I keep getting unauthorized. Did I set something up wrong? I can get the request to work correctly with curl, but not with java.

```
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", stripeClientId));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Looks like I was making the request with the wrong key. This appears to be the proper way to send this request.